# Mapping .edmx Entites properties to DTO after making changes in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am new to the concept of AutoMapping. I am using database first approach for my application so an .edmx file is generated, I have mapped entities present in my .edmx files with DTO's.

Now my problem is whenever I make changes in .edmx entities file by updating database in model browser, I have to make changes in DTO entites too manually,

So I doubt my mapping is working. Is there any way that I don't have to make those changes manually and DTO's change when I updated my .edmx file?
Or is it because I have not configured my automapper properly?

Here is my auto mapper configuration.

AutoMapperWebConfiguration.cs

```
class AutoMapperWebConfiguration 
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new UserProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new PostProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

UserProfile.cs

```
public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    { 
        Mapper.CreateMap<tabletest,tabletestDTO>();
    }
}
```

Please let me know what to add into this configuration so that I can automatically change my DTO entites evey time .edmx entities are updated.

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper cann't update your DTOs, it just maps it. A simplest workaround is to use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` [method](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) to verify your configuration at runtime:

> AutoMapper checks to make sure that every single Destination type
>   member has a corresponding type member on the source type.

Another (and much more complicated) option is to use T4 templates to generate DTOs based on entity classes.